# How to verify ios In-App Purchase on your server

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am up to build my first in-app purchase app. I would like to know whether there is a way to verify purchase on your server.

I have to build the whole user management, and I would like to know for all registered user what they already bought on their iOS devices, so that they get web app for free, or something like that. So, is there a way for me to check on Apple store side, if this user has already buy some product?

EDIT:

Scenario is like this:

User A buy app B on mobile device. After this I would like to check on my server (on my web page,...) if user A is bought app B, or (similar) which app was bought by user A.

I don't want to send message from mobile device to my server that user A buy app B, because users can reproduce this call on server even if they didn't buy app B.

I would check on server side whit app Store if user A bought app B.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Fetch the app's receipt (from the file at `[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]`) and send it to your server. Then either…

- Parse the receipt and check its signature against Apple's certificate [as described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html) (on your server, not in the app). Or,
- Send the receipt (again, from your server) to the app store for validation [as described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html).

Answer (score 6):

I just released a simple Python/Django web app ([In-App Purchase Receipt Verifier](https://github.com/lionheart/in_app_purchase_receipt_verifier)) that automatically handles the annoying part of this process (i.e., verifying the receipt on your server while maintaining cryptographic integrity). The code itself is relatively simple, but I figured others would appreciate not having to do the grunt-work here.

To use it, just make sure you have your app-specific shared secret ready to go, then go [here](https://github.com/lionheart/in_app_purchase_receipt_verifier) and click "Deploy to Heroku". Your app will be up and running within a minute.

I've also included some sample code for how to use this web app to validate your receipts within your app. Using Swift 4:

```
guard let receiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: receiptURL) else {
      return
}

let encodedData = data.base64EncodedData(options: [])
let url = URL(string: "https://your-app.herokuapp.com/verify")!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpBody = encodedData
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data,
        let object = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []),
        let json = object as? [String: Any] else {
            return
    }

    // Your application logic here.
}
task.resume()
```

Note: There are other solutions floating around on StackOverflow that suggest to do the validation completely within the app itself, but I'd highly recommend against that. From Apple's documentation in [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1):

> Use a trusted server to communicate with the App Store. Using your own server lets you design your app to recognize and trust only your server, and lets you ensure that your server connects with the App Store server. It is not possible to build a trusted connection between a user’s device and the App Store directly because you don’t control either end of that connection.

<strike>Further improvements could probably be made to add some sort of cryptographic signature within the response header so that your app can check whether the response is safe, but I'll probably add that in a future release.</strike> Done :)

Comment: This is cool, but I'm a total server noob. Does this have to deploy to Heroku, or can we deploy it on our own server?

Comment: You can definitely deploy it on your own server, but if you aren't comfortable running a Django app on your own server, Heroku will probably be easier. If you have any suggestions for improvement please open an issue on the repo and I'll see what I can do. :)

Comment: @Dan how to store the receipt data on Heroku Postgres sql and how to deploy it on own server.

Comment: @NikhilPandey Feel free to fork the project I wrote above and add that improvement!

Comment: Wow i wish i found this a few months ago when i was doing the same, nice job. I'll still shameless plug my much less user friendly/feature rich version of a receipt verifier, its node+AWS+serverless: https://github.com/OrbiLabs/appStoreVerifyReceiptProxy

Answer (score 4):

The latest information of this [`verifyReceipt`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt?changes=latest_minor) `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt` API has been **deprecated** as of **Mon, 5 Jun 2023 23:59:59 GMT** per the header `Deprecation` of response of `verifyReceipt`.

> The verifyReceipt endpoint is deprecated. To validate receipts on your server, follow the steps in Validating receipts on the device on your server. To validate in-app purchases on your server without using receipts, call the App Store Server API to get Apple-signed transaction and subscription information for your customers, or verify the AppTransaction and Transaction signed data that your app obtains. You can also get the same signed transaction and subscription information from the App Store Server Notifications V2 endpoint.

> The verifyReceipt endpoint is deprecated. **The HTTP header includes the deprecation date**, according to RFC 8594.

---

More details of ios receipt verification on the server side

- Local receipt validation on the server

  - Do the [Validating receipts on the device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/validating_receipts_on_the_device?changes=latest_minor) on your server, verify the contents of app receipts by decoding and parsing the receipt on the device
- App Store Server API

  - To validate in-app purchases on your server without using receipts, call the App Store Server API (like [Get Transaction Info](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_transaction_info?changes=latest_minor)) to get Apple-signed transaction and subscription information for your customers, or verify the [AppTransaction a](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/apptransaction?changes=latest_minor) Transaction signed data that your app obtains
  - Here is one app store server API implementation by Golang https://github.com/richzw/appstore
- App Store server Notification

  - You can also get the same signed transaction and subscription information from the [App Store Server Notifications V2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/app_store_server_notifications_v2?changes=latest_minor) endpoint

Answer (score 1):

Server can verify receipt with App Store by Http Post.
Please refer to 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use following things:
1. Make entries of users on your server along with purchase status.
2. Also you can use payment recipt provided by apple using store kit.

Also if you are using non-consumable product, then you just need a restore button for this. Please go through the apple's document for this.
https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Comment: I am not sure if we understand correctly. 1. to send message to server when user buy product is not the option because user can reproduce this call without buying product. What I would need is some API from apple to check if this user is buy this product, like Facebook API can tall you if this user is logged in your app.

Comment: you can use NSUserDefaults for this, also if you are using Non-Consumable Product, you does not need to manage this, you just need to integrate restore functionality and the result coming from this will be the purchased product Ids of user's account. You can match them with your Product Ids and perform desired actions..

Comment: No, I have Consumable Products

Comment: Then you have to make user to purchase it every time as per apple's guidline. Only thing you can use for this is to set boolean value in NSUserDefaults and check this Boolean value to perform desired actions.

Comment: We really don't understand each other. I don't have trouble with my iOS application, What I want is to check on server if user A is purchase product B.

Comment: OK lets say user A have purchased product B, and you have presented a pro version view to him. Now coming back to this particular view controller you want to check if B is purchased by A. Am I right?

Comment: No :D I would like like this. User A logged in in my system, than buy over app-Store product B, and then I would like to see on my server (my website) that user A is buy product B.

Comment: So just save the product B with purchased status to be 1 with respect to the user Id of user A.

Comment: Yes, but this I try to avoid. Because if I call web service from mobile device to set for user A that is purchased product B, User can reproduce this call and set for himself that he purchase product B even if he isn't. I would like on server side check on appStore if this user is buy product B

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
POST : https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
```

inside the post you need to send a json with the receipt, something like this

```
{"receipt-data":"the receipt data you get from the in app purchase"}
```

and then you receive a response from the servers from apple.
Remember when you are donde testing you need to switch to production

[Apple in app purchase verication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store)

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt

On this page you can find detailed information about IOS receipt verification. It is very easy. You should just send http request with payload.