# Is there a way to confirm In-App Purchases directly from server?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

Usually it looks like the `Store Kit` communicate with the `App Store` and once transaction is completed, I can inform the server to assign transaction to user logged within the **app** not within the App Store in device.

So, does server may **directly** confirm the payment from the App Store? Is it possible?

Comment: You're question isn't clear. Are you asking if Apple can send a notification to your server when a purchase is made?

Comment: yes, can it ping the server as the paypal does? or the server itself may ask the App Store if some payment is really finished?

Comment: No, Apple won't ping your server, you have to make your server request an Apple receipt validation using the receipt from the app, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013678/how-to-verify-ios-in-app-purchase-on-your-server

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track notifications regarding auto-renewable subscriptions, then this is something you can now do (as of October 2017).

From https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev0067a330b:

> If your app offers auto-renewable subscriptions, you can receive server notifications from the App Store about key events by setting up an optional URL that links to your server.

Just navigate to your app in iTunes Connect, then navigate to "App Information". Under "General Information", enter the URL you'd like to be notified in "Subscription Status URL". Then click save, and you're done.